# C# How do I remove values for a specific item in the database

Tags: c#

I'm having problems deleting from my database

I have the following

```
Member thisMember = db.Members.First(m => m.MemberID == member.MemberID);
db.Members.Remove(thisMember.Name);
db.Members.Remove(thisMember.LastName);
```

But I keep getting an invalid arguments error. Can someone assist me?

Thanks!

Comment: Databases don't work like that.  You cannot delete a single cell.  You may want to set the property.

Comment: Thanks ! Thats exactly what I did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`db.Members.Remove` is used to remove whole record (row/object) from data source. So you can remove *whole* member like this:

```
db.Member.Remove(thisMember);
```

If you want to set values of `thisMember` then you can do it like this:

```
Member thisMember = db.Members.First(m => m.MemberID == member.MemberID);
thisMember.Name = "";
// provided that it allows null value
thisMember.LastName = null;
// save changes in data source
db.SaveChanges();
```